# Django, Requests, and Django REST framework

Tags: django, python-requests, django-rest-framework

I have implemented a REST Api (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) as follows:

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['PUT'])
def updateinfo(request, id, format=None):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

which works fine when I update user info through browser.
But I have difficulties calling this Api using Requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

This is my code where I am calling the above api:

```
payload = {'id':id, ...}          
resp = requests.put(updateuserinfo_url, data=payload)
```

and this is the response that I receive:

```
resp.text 
   {"id": ["This field is required."], ...}
```

I checked `request.DATA` and it seems that it is empty. I appreciate if someone could help with finding what is wrong with my code, or if I am missing some additional settings/arguments required to make this simple request.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the django-rest framework parser decorator, in your case, you need use `@parser_classes((FormParser,))` to populate request.DATA dict. [Read more here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers)

try with that:

```
from rest_framework.parsers import FormParser


@parser_classes((FormParser,))
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['PUT'])
def updateinfo(request, id, format=None):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Thank you. Tried FormParser and JSONParser, still no chance. Just to clarify, I am calling the rest api from within another view. Does it make any difference?

Comment: Oh i guess yes, because the request object is from a "view" and not from the broswer. Can you paste your complete code?

Comment: Sigh. It was a problem with Requests package. I reinstalled the package and now it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing everything using JSON.

1. Add JSONParser, like [levi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1539655/levi) explained
2. Add custom headers to your request, like in [this example](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers)

So for you, maybe something like:

```
>>> payload = {'id':id, ...}        
>>> headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

>>> r = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Answer (score -1):

There was a problem with Requests' package. I reinstalled the package and now it is working.
Thank you all.